# Pandas multiindex to json

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I have a dataframe as below

```
    name address.office.street address.office.city address.office.country  address.office.postcode location.tracker.id
0  Name1               Street1               City1               Country1                      100         9,99,02,129
1  Name2               Street2               City2               Country2                      200         1,91,95,129
2  Name3               Street3               City3               Country3                      300           99,90,259
```

I split the column and created MultiIndex as below

```
idx = df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)
df.columns = idx
df[('location', 'tracker', 'id')] = df[('location', 'tracker', 'id')].str.split(',')
print(df)


    name  address                                    location
     NaN   office                                     tracker
     NaN   street   city   country postcode                id
0  Name1  Street1  City1  Country1      100  [9, 99, 02, 129]
1  Name2  Street2  City2  Country2      200  [1, 91, 95, 129]
2  Name3  Street3  City3  Country3      300     [99, 90, 259]
```

I want to convert this to nested json. May I know the pandas way to convert this into below json.

> [ {
>       "name": "Name1",
>       "address": {
>           "office": {
>               "street": "Street1",
>               "city": "City1",
>               "country": "Country1",
>               "postcode": 100
>           }
>       },
>       "location": {
>           "tracker": {
>               "id": [
>                   "9",
>                   "99",
>                   "02",
>                   "129"
>               ]
>           }
>       } }, {
>       "name": "Name2",
>       "address": {
>           "office": {
>               "street": "Street2",
>               "city": "City2",
>               "country": "Country2",
>               "postcode": 200
>           }
>       },
>       "location": {
>           "tracker": {
>               "id": [
>                   "1",
>                   "91",
>                   "95",
>                   "129"
>               ]
>           }
>       } }, {
>       "name": "Name3",
>       "address": {
>           "office": {
>               "street": "Street3",
>               "city": "City3",
>               "country": "Country3",
>               "postcode": 300
>           }
>       },
>       "location": {
>           "tracker": {
>               "id": [
>                   "99",
>                   "90",
>                   "259"
>               ]
>           }
>       } } ]

While I can get the above result with below code, it becomes slow when the number of records(df.shape[0]) are high.

```
nested_dict = lambda: defaultdict(nested_dict)
result = nested_dict()

result_list = []
for cntr in range(df.shape[0]):
    for i, j in df.iteritems():
        value = j[cntr]
        if not pd.isnull(i[2]):
            result[i[0]][i[1]][i[2]] = value
        elif not pd.isnull(i[1]):
            result[i[0]][i[1]] = value
        elif not pd.isnull(i[0]):
            result[i[0]] = value

    result_list.append(deepcopy(result))

print(json.dumps(result_list, indent=4))
```

I look to simplify this similar to

```
(df.groupby(level=['level0']).apply(lambda df: df.xs(df.name))).to_json()
```

But, could not get the results as expected.

Comment: I don't think you will find a function to do this, you will probably end up using defaultdicts as you have already tried..